# Reward user for Installing App

Tags: mobile, reward, reward-system

My question is: How do i reward user for installing the app shown on the video add or banner? In other words how i keep track if a user downloads the app that i advertise and then reward him with points in game.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you will put some kind of unique identifier in the links in your advertisement and you would to track this identifier and later user it when the app is installed.

You can also display some kind of code on the app download page that the user can enter into the app to get their reward.

Another option is to create a custom landing page for the user to download the app from and have the user register to download the app and associate the registration with the app.

Comment: But i do t wanna do this directly thru links im thinking maybe is possible to reward my user from download the app that they see on the admob/chartboos banner. Would should i do alex?

Comment: Without more information I can't be of help? Are they downloading the app from your server? What kind of app is? What device does it run? How are you advertising? Where does the advertising link go? Explain your specific use case. Click edit on your question and update it with what specifically you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok here it goes: im new at developing apps so im just gonna give all the info the i know.

Comment: The app ia a 2d game created on buildbox 2. Im advertising using chartboost. The app is only for googleplay. So what i really want is this: My user see the banner on my game than clicks on it then it opens the advertised game page and he downloads it. When he comes back i want to reward him.

Comment: Yeah, not sure what you can do here. Your game is made used pre-packaged software. Not sure how you could customize it to do this and you aren't hosting it your self. You can see if Google Play offers anything for what you are trying to do otherwise I have no other suggestions. You should update your question with this information so someone with experience with this can answer. Your title and question are too vague to get attention from the people that can help.